# Wordpress fatal error: out of memory issue with plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, memory, plugins

I am having an issue with a Wordpress plugin causing a "fatal error: out of memory". The issue is with a specific plugin called Views from wp-types.com.

Here is the specific error: Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 33030144) (tried to allocate 7672 bytes) in /homepages/24/d300504206/htdocs/TEST/wp-content/plugins/types/embedded/views/image.php on line 481

And the page where it is occuring: http://udtech-usa.com/TEST/products/

I have tried:

- Adding a line to the wp-config file to adjust the memory.
- Reinstalled the Views plugin (and Types plugin)
- Added a line to the .htaccess file to max out memory
- Checked with the host 1&1.com to see if the memory was sufficient
  (120M)

This is a dev wordpress site with an existing wordpress site at the root. I'm not sure if that has anything to do with the memory issue or not but I was having some trouble uploading images when I first started on this site as well.

Comment: 33mb is not a lot of memory. Are you able to increase the amount of memory Apache has access to?

Comment: I'm not super technical when it comes to Apache. How would I go about this? The 1&1 hosting panel is designed very poorly, I wish they would just use cpanel.

Comment: It's probably not something can change if its shared hosting, maybe increasing the capacity of your hosting plan might help as it looks like you'll need more memory on your server

Comment: I think that plugin's image.php file is broken

Comment: Thanks scrowler for the help, upgraded my memory just waiting on it to take effect.